# How to convert a shapefile into a WMS?

Tags: shapefile, wms, mapbender

Can anyone tell me  how to transform a shapefile into a WMS and then load it into mapbender?

Answer (score 3):

WMS is not a data format but a webservice specification for map images. If you want to publish a shape file as a WMS, you might use something like geoserver (http://geoserver.org/) and then visualise it with mapbender (http://www.mapbender.org/WMS).